# Can we replace 此生或彼生 in 文言文 with something less ambiguous but not longer?

Tags: literary-chinese

### TLDR Background

In his text [此生或彼生](https://zh.wikisource.org/zh-hans/%E3%80%8C%E6%AD%A4%E7%94%9F%E6%88%96%E5%BD%BC%E7%94%9F%E3%80%8D) Lu Xun takes apart a proponent of literary Chinese (named, I think, Wang Maozu). Wang had attempted to argue the superiority of Literary Chinese by pointing out that

> 這一個學生或是那一個學生

could be recast in Literary Chinese as the reduction

> 此生或彼生。

Wang’s argument immediately struck me as somewhat disingenuous, since several 一 and 是 can be omitted in colloquial Chinese.

Lu Xun responded with the valid criticism that 生 in Wang’s reduction was ambiguous and could denote 學生，秀才 and 這一世/來生。

While I believe that f.e. 孔子家語 offers many examples of Classical Chinese being read ambiguously by the Ancients, I wonder, how hard it would have been for Wang to make a better argument for this single case.

### Question

Could Wang simply have said

> 此徒或彼弟

to make his meaning clear without lengthening the phrase?

Is there another, less ambiguous, option of equal or even smaller length?

I suspect that most 此A彼B patterns involve A and B verbs [此起彼落、此呼彼应], not nouns. Though 此界彼疆 might be an exception. But perhaps the 此A彼B pattern is not even the smartest way to go.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the focus/contexts of the conservation, 學生, and 人生 are not very easily mistaken one for another.

師嘆曰: 儒**子**不可**教**也.

問: 此(學)**生**或彼(學)**生**(如此不受**教**)?

婦哭訴: **生**不如**死**.

問: 此**生**(this life)或來**生**(next life)?

Answer (score 0):

Though my knowledge of classic Chinese is limited, I don't think ancient Chinese would express an idea such as "這一個學生或是那一個學生", or "此生或彼生". To me, "這一個學生或是那一個學生" is kind of awkward. I'd use "這兩個學生那一個...". For example:
"這一個學生或是那一個學生較聰明?" => "這兩個學生那一個較聰明?" => "此二生孰慧?"
"這一個人或那一個人比較孝順?" => "這兩個人那一個比較孝順?" => "此二人孰孝?"
Though there is nothing wrong with "此生或彼生孰慧?", it just sounds unnatural to me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can say, 此人或彼人。

生 originally means life, reproduce， giving birth to。 It is indirectly used for youth as in 晚生，后生，小生，学生。 When 生 is used by itself, people would not think of the transformed meaning.